# Dockerized nginx shuts down after a few seconds

Tags: linux, docker

I'm working with Ubuntu 18 and I´m trying to run a dockerized nginx with a shared file between the host machine and the container: `/home/ric/wrkspc/djangodocker/djangodocker/nginx.conf`

I do so by running the following command, after which I'm prompted with container's ID:

```
$ sudo docker container run -v /home/ric/wrkspc/djangodocker/djangodocker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -d nginx
facc4d32db31de85d6f360e581bc7d36f257ff66953814e985ce6bdf708c3ad0
```

Now, if I try to list all the running containers, the nginx one doesn't appear listed:

```
(env) ric@x:~/wrkspc/djangodocker/djangodocker$ sudo docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
36090ff0759c        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 days ago          Up 3 days           0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   boring_panini
```

Sometimes, if I run the `docker ls command` fast enough, I can see the nginx container listed for just a few seconds and then it disappears.

Why is the nginx container not being listed?

Comment: Without knowing anything else about your config: did you remember to set `daemon off;`? I always forget that...

Comment: Surely your container has stopped, maybe for a configuration error. You can see logs of the container with `docker logs <OUTPUT OF DOCKER RUN>`

Comment: `docker ps -a` also lists terminated containers with their status und exit code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think container immediately exits after started.

can you troubleshoot by looking into docker logs using the command
**docker logs containerID**

Also, you can try running the container interactively to identify the error without using **-d** option

Comment: Thank you. Using the `logs` subcommand I found that the problem was this: `nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1`. Oh, well.